# What sign does i have?

Tags: arithmetic

It is imagined that $i$ squared is $-1$

Leonhard Euler found his "Identity" as (sorry, can't do the formatting)

> $e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$

by mixing $i$ into $e$, separating the real and imaginary parts, giving $\cos$ and $\sin$ as a Taylor series, $\sin π$ being zero .

He tacitly assumes $i$ is $+ i,$ whereas $i$ squared is $-1$.

Is $i$ really $+i$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Yes, $i$ is the thing (complex number) such that $i^2=-1$. And $+i$ is the same as $+1i=(+1)(i)=i$.

Comment: This is the same as $2$ being the same as $+2$ (positive $2$), as opposed to $-2$ (negative $2$). What else are you wanting $+i$ to be, if not $i$?

Comment: No, Euler's argument has nothing whatever to do with positive and negative parts; it proceeds by considering the _real_ and _imaginary_ part of the series defining $e^{i\pi}$.

Comment: Yes, $i$ is really $+i$. That does _not_ say $i$ is positive; in fact it's neither positive nor negative

Comment: $i=-i$ would imply $2i=0$ , but the complex numbers have no zero divisors. Hence , the two numbers $z$ satisfying $z^2=-1$ are distinct. The above formula however also works with $-i$ as you can see with the Euler formula.

Comment: " in fact it's neither positive nor negative " How can i interact with other numbers, which are either positive or negative? You mean i is just regarded as a unit of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

Signs are used in the real numbers to depict whether a number is greater than or less than $0.$ However, in the complex numbers this concept of "less than" and "greater than" isn't really seen as meaningful. (You can define a well-ordering of the complex numbers, but it's just not very useful.)

So, $i$ is just $i.$ It doesn't have a sign in the way that a real number does. And $-i$ is just $-1 \cdot i,$ so the point one unit down from the origin in the complex plane instead of up.

Answer (score 1):

The misunderstandings vanish when you see a complex number $x+iy$ as a pair of reals $(x,y)$ with the product convention $(x,y)(u,v)=(xu-yv,xv+yu)$, which induces $(0,1)^2=(-1,0)$. Of course we also have $(0,-1)^2=-1$.

Now your question reduces to "is $(0,1)$ really $(0,1)$ ?" [and not $(0,-1)$].

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $i$ is equivalent to $+i$. There is also its negative counterpart $-i$. Whereas when only concerning yourself the real number line, the negative sign prepended to a positive number $n$ simply means "move to the left of 0 by the magnitude of $n$", when thinking about the complex plane, "left" and "right" of 0 kind of become useless. When you negate a complex number $z$, you distribute the negative to its real and imaginary component. In order to think about the negative sign (or a multiplication of $-1$) attached to $z$, we need to consider it a rotation about the origin (0) of 180 degrees. Thus, if $i$ is thought about as a vector with a 90 degree notation and a magnitude of 1, then multiplying it by $-1$ which is the same thing as rotating it 180 degrees will yield $-i$, a number when thought of as a vector also has a magnitude of 1, but since it was rotated from 90 degrees by 180 degrees, it must have an argument (or angle) of 270 degrees.

As is conventional notation, most people drop the "$+$" sign when talking about positive numbers.

I think this was an excellent question. I'm not sure why it has two downvotes.

Comment: Relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407872/is-the-number-of-values-the-sign-function-can-take-on-a-ring-signedness-of-a

Answer (score 0):

The $\text{sign}$ function is usually extended to the complex plane as $\text{sign } z=\frac z{|z|}$ (for instance, in Wolfram Mathematica). Thus the $\text{sign}$ function can get infinite number of different values on the complex plane. So, we will see that $\text{sign } i=i$.

Interestingly enough, on split-complex (hyperbolic) numbers the sign function [can take only $9$ different values](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407872/is-the-number-of-values-the-sign-function-can-take-on-a-ring-signedness-of-a).